# Hola, alguien sabe utilizar OpenCV en Python para filtrado espacial de imágenes, para quitarle el ruido a una imagen que no me funciona

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: hice esto, pero no me funciona, intente aplicar los filtros para eliminar ruido a toda la imagen y tampoco funciona]

hice esto, pero no me funciona, intente aplicar los filtros para eliminar ruido a toda la imagen y tampoco funciona

este es mi código, ayuda!
hice esto, pero no me funciona, intente aplicar los filtros para eliminar ruido a toda la imagen y tampoco funciona

este es mi código, ayuda!

```
import cv2 # OpenCV para computer vision
import numpy as np # Para cálculo de matrices
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #Para graficar
import os #Habilita el manejo de directorios



#Leyendo y mostrando imagen de referencia
Ruta_drive = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/cursoImagenes/Input.jpg'
Imagen = cv2.imread(Ruta_drive)#Lee
Imagen=Imagen[:,:,[2,1,0]]#Organiza
print('Mostrando imagen de referencia: ')
plt.imshow(Imagen.astype('uint8'),vmin=0, vmax=255) #Muestra
plt.show()
print('')


#Mejorando problemas de ruido 
[Fl, Cl, Ch]=Imagen.shape 
Resultado=np.zeros((Fl,Cl,Ch))
#Crea el kernel
kernel = np.ones((20,20),np.float32)/400 #24 vecinos
#Filtra la imagen utilizando el kernel anterior
Resultado = cv2.filter2D(Imagen,-1,kernel)
#Muestra resultado
print('Imagen mejorada 1 ')
plt.imshow(Resultado.astype('uint8'),vmin=0, vmax=255) 
plt.show()
print('')
```

este es mi código, ayuda!

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon el código como texto, no como imagen. También tienes que definir "no funciona": se cae, se pega, no hace nada, deja la imagen en negro ...

Comment: @Jhony Alexis Martinez, acompaña tu código en formato de texto en vez de añadir una imagen porfavor!

Comment: @Alexci listo amigo

Comment: @CandidMoe Listo ya lo puse, a lo que me refiero es q no me quita el ruido de la imagen, debe quedar como la imagen q añadí, la de abajo y queda igual a la de arriba